# ERRORS in NetBeans " Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");"

Tags: java, mysql

i am using netbeans 8.2 and mysql 8.0 and inport mysql connector 8.0.11 to the library file as well for my following java codes,

```
package jdbc;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JDBC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String SQL="Insert into Customer Values('C111','Somadasa','Matugama',34000)";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/ThogaKade", "root", "ftwxy");
        Statement stm=connection.createStatement();
        stm.executeUpdate(SQL);
    }

}
```

but following lines have been highlighted
`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
`Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/ThogaKade", "root", "mysql");`

with the message 'unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
----'
how could fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify that `main` throws the `Exception`(s). Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String SQL = "Insert into Customer Values('C111','Somadasa','Matugama',34000)";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/ThogaKade", "root", "ftwxy");
    Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
    stm.executeUpdate(SQL);
}
```

**Or**, you can use a `try-catch` (preferably with a `try-with-Resources`) like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String SQL = "Insert into Customer Values('C111','Somadasa','Matugama',34000)";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/ThogaKade", "root",
            "ftwxy"); Statement stm = connection.createStatement()) {
        stm.executeUpdate(SQL);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The advantage of a `try-with-Resources` is it will `close()` your `Connection` and `Statement`(s) correctly. Finally, you haven't actually needed to explicitly load a JDBC driver with `Class.forName(String)` since Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Just add throws in method signature, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
   //method body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because `Class.forName` and `DriverManager.getConnection` throws `Exception` that needs to be handled.
The simplest approach to fix this error is to make your `main` method throw `Exception`.
Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // your code here
}
```

Another approach would be to enclose your code inside a `try-catch` block.
Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String SQL="Insert into Customer Values('C111','Somadasa','Matugama',34000)";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/ThogaKade", "root", "ftwxy");
        Statement stm=connection.createStatement();
        stm.executeUpdate(SQL);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps